# MS Access to SQL Server - Newbie needing advice/direction

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

So I have been working with multiple different MS Access apps at work (about 8) for different departments. And it looks as though there are going to stand up a SQL Server at work, which makes sense from a capacity/integrations standpoint.

Soooo......I have experience with Access, SQL and VBA, but having never used any of it in a SQL Server capacity, are there any resources for learning, books, websites, etc where I can start? Can you "face plate" (yeah sorry that is my term I suppose, and may sound ridiculous) access applications on the SQL Server app so that I can continue to develop, utilize and have end users utilize SQL Server through these access applications?

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on how you access your datum through with these access apps. Have you built for instance C# or VB applications to access these datum through OleDB or ODBC DSN, or do you use Access Forms applications which are part of your database project?

Comment: Er, seems to me that that question is pretty clear that these are Access applications using a Jet/ACE data store, so the C#/VB/OLEDB/ODCBC issues are complete red herrings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of foilks have successfuly upsized their Access apps to SQL Server with a minimm of trouble.  There will be some tweaking required and some areas which were slow in Access that you can speed up.   Do ensure the users do lots of testing of course.   For now avoid merge replication on SQL Server as that and Access seems to have some troubles.

See my [Random Thoughts on SQL Server Upsizing from Microsoft Access Tips page](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/sqlserverupsizing.htm)

There is a  tool from the SQL Server group which is better than the Upsizing Wizard that comes with Access
[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA Access)](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/solutions/migration/access/default.mspx)

Comment: Tony is right -- it's generally pretty painless, unless your Access app does lots of bad things. The key point is that your app should be retrieving the minimum number of records necessary for the user to do her work.

Answer (score 1):

[W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) has good tutorials and quizzes in many fields including SQL and ASP.NET.

You can find articles about using SQL server on [SQLserverCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Articles/Video).

Comment: Thanks very much! This will certainly help get me started!

Comment: Hmm, the SQL Server Central site "Free registration required...
To read the rest of this article, and access thousands of other articles, we ask you to register on the site and subscribe to our newsletters."    That site won't be on my recommended reading list.

Answer (score 1):

As for SQL Server sites, I'm favoring [Simple Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/) these days. I think it has something for everybody, newbies and seasoned professionals.

I like their "cribsheets", with the facts on most SQL Server resources (Reporting Services, Security, OLAP, pivot, regex,...).